# How to scrape all values from a table like HTML DIV structure without missing some of them?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

Im just 3 months into learning python and I run into a little problem while building a Finance Yahoo web Scraper.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import requests
import openpyxl



index = 'MSFT'

headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36' }

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/financials?p=MSFT'

read_data = requests.get(url,headers=headers, timeout=5)
content = read_data.content
soup_is = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')





ls = []
for l in soup_is.find_all('div') and soup_is.find_all('span'):
    ls.append(l.string)


new_ls = list(filter(None,ls))
new_ls = new_ls[45:]

is_data = list(zip(*[iter(new_ls)]*6))
Income_st = pd.DataFrame(is_data[0:])
print(Income_st)
```

Everything goes smoothly when I noticed that the content of rows "Diluted EPS" and "Basic EPS" weren't copied.
While inspecting the source code ive noticed that the EPS values are stored in the div tag if I can say it like that? Instead of the `<span>"Value"</span>` underneath it.

```
<div class="Ta(c) Py(6px) Bxz(bb) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(120px) Miw(100px)--pnclg Bgc($lv1BgColor) fi-row:h_Bgc($hoverBgColor) D(tbc)" data-test="fin-col">**<span>39,240,000</span>**</div>

<div class="Ta(c) Py(6px) Bxz(bb) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(120px) Miw(100px)--pnclg D(tbc)" data-test="fin-col"**>9.70<**/div>
```

Any idea on how I can fix the code to get those values out? Also any idea how I can extract data separately on two different pages "Annually" and "Quartely"?

I was trying to change the tags, attributes etc but with no avail. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to select your elements more specific and use [`stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) in this case to extract the infos from the data rows:

```
[e.stripped_strings for e in soup.select('[data-test="fin-row"]')]
```

and the columns:

```
soup.select_one('div:has(>[data-test="fin-row"])').previous_sibling.stripped_strings
```

##### Example

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
index = 'MSFT'
headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36' }

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/financials?p=MSFT'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url,headers=headers, timeout=5).text)

pd.DataFrame(
    [e.stripped_strings for e in soup.select('[data-test="fin-row"]')],
    columns=soup.select_one('div:has(>[data-test="fin-row"])').previous_sibling.stripped_strings
)
```

##### Output

|  | Breakdown | ttm | 6/30/2022 | 6/30/2021 | 6/30/2020 | 6/30/2019 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Total Revenue | 204,094,000 | 198,270,000 | 168,088,000 | 143,015,000 | 125,843,000 |
| 1 | Cost of Revenue | 64,984,000 | 62,650,000 | 52,232,000 | 46,078,000 | 42,910,000 |
| 2 | Gross Profit | 139,110,000 | 135,620,000 | 115,856,000 | 96,937,000 | 82,933,000 |
| 3 | Operating Expense | 56,295,000 | 52,237,000 | 45,940,000 | 43,978,000 | 39,974,000 |
| 4 | Operating Income | 82,815,000 | 83,383,000 | 69,916,000 | 52,959,000 | 42,959,000 |
| 5 | Net Non Operating Interest Income Expense | 423,000 | 31,000 | -215,000 | 89,000 | 76,000 |
| 6 | Other Income Expense | -650,000 | 302,000 | 1,401,000 | -12,000 | 653,000 |
| 7 | Pretax Income | 82,588,000 | 83,716,000 | 71,102,000 | 53,036,000 | 43,688,000 |
| 8 | Tax Provision | 15,139,000 | 10,978,000 | 9,831,000 | 8,755,000 | 4,448,000 |
| 9 | Net Income Common Stockholders | 67,449,000 | 72,738,000 | 61,271,000 | 44,281,000 | 39,240,000 |
| 10 | Diluted NI Available to Com Stockholders | 67,449,000 | 72,738,000 | 61,271,000 | 44,281,000 | 39,240,000 |
| 11 | Basic EPS | - | 9.70 | 8.12 | 5.82 | 5.11 |
| 12 | Diluted EPS | - | 9.65 | 8.05 | 5.76 | 5.06 |
| 13 | Basic Average Shares | - | 7,496,000 | 7,547,000 | 7,610,000 | 7,673,000 |
| 14 | Diluted Average Shares | - | 7,540,000 | 7,608,000 | 7,683,000 | 7,753,000 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 26 | Net Income from Continuing Operation Net Minority Interest | 67,449,000 | 72,738,000 | 61,271,000 | 44,281,000 | 39,240,000 |
| 27 | Total Unusual Items Excluding Goodwill | -547,000 | 334,000 | 1,303,000 | 28,000 | 710,000 |
| 28 | Total Unusual Items | -547,000 | 334,000 | 1,303,000 | 28,000 | 710,000 |
| 29 | Normalized EBITDA | 99,314,000 | 99,905,000 | 83,831,000 | 68,395,000 | 57,346,000 |
| 30 | Tax Rate for Calcs | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 31 | Tax Effect of Unusual Items | -100,269 | 43,420 | 182,420 | 4,620 | 72,420 |